# Need "Editable Dropdown"

Tags: html, list, drop-down-menu

I need a white box, with a gray border to appear below this text box when the button is clicked. The drop down will have say, 5 to 10 lines of text, which hav the look and feel of the URL drop down at the top of your browser.

Can I do this with a div?

```
<script> function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } </script>
<input name="media" id="media" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="..." onclick="$('keypad').style.display='inline-block';"/>

<div id="keypad" onmouseout="$('keypad').style.display='none'" style="display:none; background:#FFF; vertical-align:top;">
    Canvas
    Steel
    Vinyl
    Paper
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616940/editable-dropdown

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616940/editable-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Simple Drop down with CSS:

```
<div id="mine">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>some title here
      <ul>
        <li>Discription about the title</li>
        <li>as many as you like</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS file:

```
#nav    {margin: 0;
 padding: 7px 6px 0;
 line-height:100%;}

 #nav ul    {display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width:200px;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 z-index:2;}

 #nav li:hover > ul  {display: block;}
```

And, of course, easily customisable with CSS.